# Append to or create an HDF5 file in Julia

Tags: io, julia, hdf5

```
julia> using HDF5
```

I don't seem to be able to create a file in `r+` mode in Julia.

```
julia> fid = h5open("/tmp/test.h5", "r+")
...
ERROR: Cannot access file /tmp/test.h5
...
```

However:

```
julia> fid = h5open("/tmp/test.h5", "w")
HDF5 data file: /tmp/test.h5
```

Is this the intended behaviour? If so, what is the right way to append to an HDF5 file, and create if it doesn't exist?

My attempt:

```
close(h5open("/tmp/test.h5", "w")) ## looks ugly to me

for dataset in ["A", "B", "C"]:

    A = long_operation_which_returns_lots_of_data()

    h5open("/tmp/test.h5", "r+") do file
        write(file, "group/$dataset", A)
    end
end
```

EDIT: In my scenario, each loop iteration takes a long time to compute and generates a lot of data, which stays in memory. Writing to file at each iteration and clearing the object from memory is therefore necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `close(h5open(...)) # look ugly` in the question WILL clobber (i.e. delete the contents of) any existing file.

A workaround for appending could be to check for file existence using `isfile`. Like:

```
h5open("/tmp/test.h5",isfile("/tmp/test.h5") ? "r+" : "w") do file
       write(file,"group/J",[10,11,12,13])
end
```

You could also try `try`:

```
f = try
    h5open("/tmp/non.h5","r+") 
catch e 
    if isa(e,ErrorException) 
        h5open("/tmp/non.h5","w")
    else
        throw(e)
    end
end
```

In any case, extra ugliness can be safely tucked away in a function and away from the main flow.

When opening a non-existing file there are some error messages from the HDF5 C library. IIRC there is a method to turn them off.

Comment: clobbering would be fine, since that call is placed outside the loop. My hope had been that opening a file with `r+` would have created a file just like `w` does (and I don't see why it shouldn't), so I could have removed that line all together and just opened the file inside the loop. Letting the exception be raised when you know that the file doesn't exist doesn't seem great either. The first option you suggest looks best to me.

Comment: Probably better not to open and close a file within the loop. It is more efficient to open once outside the loop.

Comment: This is not the case in my loop, as each iteration takes a long time and generates a lot of data which stays in memory. Saving that to disk and clearing the memory is necessary at each iteration. I will update the question with this info.